# Why is this MOSFET Differential Pair On on the Right-Hand Side?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, ltspice

Could someone please explain to me both the qualitative and quantitative analysis of the following MOSFET differential amp circuit, to explain why Vs = -0.5 V and the Right-Hand MOSFET is "on"?[image]

EDIT - a little more detail

The goal of the circuit is to have M2 ( left-hand side ) MOSFET turn on at Vg=~0.25V instead of Vg=~0.7V with point S tied to ground. The current source was the only method I could think of to achieve this.

Comment: The schematic part is too small to read easily. Could you make it larger? And welcome to StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit model uses an ideal current source. This source will lower its sinking terminal to as low a voltage as necessary to obtain 25 uA current. In your circuit that means lowering it to -0.5 V and turning on M1.

If you implemented this circuit on a chip, you'd use a current mirror there, not an ideal current source, so the behavior will be different.

If you want to get at least slightly more realistic behavior, you can include a resistor in parallel with the current source. But you'll still end up with a negative voltage at `Vs`, which isn't what will happen in the real circuit.

If you more realistic behavior than that, you will probably need to design the actual current mirror circuit and include it in your model, so that the compliance voltage behavior of the source can be included.

Comment: The current circuit produces exactly the kind of functionality I need, but I need to build a real-world circuit. I have attempted the basic current mirror and Wilson's and both won't work - (a) basic won't work because I operate in low output voltages 0 to 1 V and this circuit won't work well in that range (b) Wilson's won't work because I only have a 1V supply and the lower transistors can't turn "on". Do you have any suggestions on current mirror designs that would work in this case?

Comment: @OzymandiusAlexandria, can you use a negative supply voltage?

Comment: No...I have a +1V rail to work with.